# Promisify a list of elements within an array

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I can't seem to find examples showing how you'd go about using promises with a list (array, in this instance, or others...). For example, I have a list:

```
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

And I'd like to perform an operation, and once they're all complete (resolved), pass the results to another function. I'm using the deferred approach, but is there a cleaner solution?

```
Promise
    .map(result, function(number) {
        var defer = Promise.pending();

        setTimeout(function() {
            return defer.resolve(number * 2);
        }, 2000);

        return defer.promise;
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Thanks for the help, in advance.

Comment: Use `Promise.map` from bluebird :D

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't more clean. The someFunc is asynchronous, so the solutions there appeared to work well with synschronous operations. Updated the question for more clarity.

Comment: Return a promise in .map and it'll wait for it

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I updated the code to using defers, however, I thought there would be an easier way?

Comment: Your code should've been waiting for promises anyway, promisify at the lowest possible API level and use promises app-wide, for example in `setTimeout` you can use `Promise.delay` instead.

Comment: Great! I was curious instead of using the 

'new Promise(function(res, rej) { ... }'  is there a way to use `Promise.method` or `Promise.promisify` for the function? If so, I can't seem to figure out what to return from that given function to resolve it, since `return Promise.resolve` doesn't seem to work.

@BenjaminGruenbaum

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises

Comment: Thanks for the link. It appears they also use the `new Promise` constructor and return the `resolve` and `reject`